# azure api manager steps to create pfx file for custom domains

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-api-management

We are able to create azure api manager. it has default azure specific urls for management,portal, proxy,scm.

we want to change these URLs to different format.is it possible for someone provide steps for getting pfx file mainly from letsencrypt.

as per my understanding we need to use for getting certificates
sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d mycustomdomain.com

consider for example mycustomdomain.com is proxy url for which we need to generate certificate. 
this url must be present as A name in some dns system. but since our url is not associated with any IP or other record we can not proceed in this case.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are steps to create pfx certificate with letsencrypt.

## Problem statement

Azure API management service provide default url for accessing backend API.This url is known as proxy url and has format like .azure.api.net.
Azure also provide facility to create custom url by providing url name, pfx certificate and certificate password.

## Steps to generate pfx file

### install certbot on your ubantu box (you can check similar steps online for other OS)

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
- sudo add-apt-repository universe
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install  certbot

### retrieve txt record

certbot -d **api.mycompanydomain.com** --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly

It will provide txt value to add in our azure dns zone. Please add same in dns zone as txt value. Once done click enter. It will generate certificates in /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mycompanydomain.com

### create pfx file

visit /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mycompanydomain.com and run following command

sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out api.mycompanydomain.com.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem

it will create pfx file in current working directory which you can use while creating custom domains

### map default proxy url to custom url as cname

once you configure this custom url you can map your custom url to default url in azure dns zone.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with LetsEncrypt, but for APIM's custom domains you should not create A record in DNS, instead you create CNAME record for your custom domain that points to default APIM hostname, i.e. xxx.azure-api.net. You could go for A record and use APIM's IP address, but that would not be stable as IP may change if some disaster occurs, and will change if service deleted/undeleted, or joined/removed from vnet.

Comment: thanks for your response. yes you are correct we can create cname instead of A record.  as per my understanding when we create azure api manager it create by default 4 end points. management, proxy, portal, scm. i am interested in changing scm and proxy url. in order to achieve this can i say i need to follow steps 1] create cname in azure dns with pointing my by default created proxy url 2] create certificate for my cname     but when i am following this step i am not sure why azure portal provided facility to update custom domains with pfx certificates.

Comment: i am taking reference of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: 1. Yes, you can use any DNS provider to create a CNAME record, APIM would not care at all as it does not maintain record itself. 2. Yes, APIM expects you to already have PFX certificate. It's needed because APIM will use provided certificate to establish HTTPS connection with clients and that requires it to have access to private key.